# use awayjs from npm repository

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I really interest in developing games and data visualization projects with awayjs library, but I can't orginize well my workflow to start using it.

First of all I made the standart workflow with gulp, npm node_modules and so on. It's okey build, bundle and browserSync greeter example.

Then I install awayjs library from npm repository:

```
npm install awayjs-full --save dev
```

NPM includes awayjs-full library in node_modules local repository. And now I have ability to use all awayjs typescript classes for develop applications:

```
// main.ts
import * as awayjs from "awayjs-full";

class Away3D {

   private _view: awayjs.View;
   constructor() {
       this.init();
   }

   private init(): void {
       this.initEngine();
   };

   private initEngine(): void {
       this._view = new awayjs.View(new awayjs.DefaultRenderer());
   }
};
window.onload = function () {
     new Away3D();
}
```

Typescript see every class and let use it in source code. But when I try to bundle javascript compiled code, the bundle gulp task through error: 'can not find module "awayjs-full"', that means that .js compiled file cannot require this library even if it store in npm repository. What I should do to let javascript finally require this lib ?!

Comment: What are you using to bundle all libraries together? It may need to be given a parameter to inform it as to where you have awayjs-full. (eg, something that will map "awayjs-full" to "node_modules/awayjs-full")

Comment: I use a gulp task with sourcemaps generation and uglify gulp plugin. That is source code: https://github.com/officefish/typescript_practice

Comment: As far as I understand the previous scripts use bower repository for require jquery or jasmine modules. Becouse of there is no bower.json and bower support in awayjs at the moment I can not install .js awayjs in bower rep. But there is a lot of bundles in node_modules repo of awayjs. I suppose I can some how link it with my .js files but I don't exactly understand how.

Answer (score 0):

That was the problem for me, because I didn't exactly understand from where generated javascript code require the javascript dependencies. I thought I use npm node modules for working in development enviroment and bower for runtime, but in this case all functions even the bundle gulp task use the same npm reposity. So if you have same problems first of all check npm repository of requiring module, look at the package.json and be sure that it has a correct link on main js library. In my case there was a index.js setting in root of repository whick exactly didn't exist. That was I got problem with requiring awayjs.